# How to enable registerHealthIndicator programatically via configuration class

Tags: java, spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I noticed that the `registerHealthIndicator` attribute can be set via application properties as mentioned [here](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#health-endpoint)

```
management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled: true
management.health.ratelimiters.enabled: true

resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  configs:
    default:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
```

By setting via properties it can be made `true` or would be `false` by [default](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/master/resilience4j-spring-boot2/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/circuitbreaker/monitoring/health/CircuitBreakersHealthIndicator.java#L103).

I had created the circuit breaker programmatically as a @Bean

```
CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                .slidingWindowType(SlidingWindowType.TIME_BASED)
                .slidingWindowSize(10)
                .minimumNumberOfCalls(6)
                .failureRateThreshold(50)
                .slowCallDurationThreshold(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .slowCallRateThreshold(50)
                .build();
```

and wanted to enable `registerHealthIndicator` to `true`. Is there any method in the [CircuitBreakerConfig](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/master/resilience4j-circuitbreaker/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/circuitbreaker/CircuitBreakerConfig.java#L100) to enable the HealthIndicator to `true`. Or is there any other workaround?